# Modifying Notepad++ spaces/tab/crlf views?

Tags: notepad++, tabs, crlf

Menu item *View/Show Symbol* has 3 choices<sup>*</sup>:

- Show white space and tab
- Show end of line
- Show all characters

These do not do what I want. Is there a possibility to<sup>**</sup>:

1. Shows tabs and CR/LF but not spaces?
2. Display something else for CR and LF then the IMO ugly white on black symbols 'CR' and 'LF'?

<sup>* I find it strange that *white space and tab* and *end of line* are mutually exclusive, but that's another issue.</sup>
<sup>** I know, two questions, but the answer for both may point in the same direction.</sup>

Comment: I don't think that is possible.

Comment: Those are the way that the underlying Scintilla editor handles special-character display. PythonScript plugin `editor.setRepresentation()` can affect some characters, but spaces, tabs, and EOL are special case, and won't change the way you expect. See [this Notepad++ community forum topic](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/community/topic/14045/invisible-characters-unwanted/16) for manipulation of other characters (not TAB, SPACE, or EOL).  And if you do try `editor.setRepresentation()` for TAB/SPACE/EOL, it ends up in the ugly black symbols that you don't like (Scintilla design, again)